# Creating SQL view by joining 7 Tables

Tags: mysql, join, mysql-workbench, sql-view

I want to create a view by joining 7 tables. I have created also, but it is not showing any data from real tables I am using to join.

At 1st I have created view by joining 2 tables only. It worked fine and showing data,

```
CREATE VIEW tbi_dd_detail_view AS
SELECT 
    d.dd_metric_config_id,
    d.metric_name,
    d.keywords,
    d.domain_id,
    d.is_active,
    c.dd_query_id,
    c.datasource_id,
    c.query,
    c.virtual_query_name
FROM
    tbi_dd_config_master d
        JOIN
    tbi_dd_custom_query_config c ON d.dd_metric_config_id = c.dd_metric_config_id
```

Sample data:

[image]
Similar way I created view for 7 tables. It created, but not showing any data

```
CREATE VIEW tbi_dd_detail_view AS
    SELECT 
        d.dd_metric_config_id,
        d.metric_name,
        d.keywords,
        d.domain_id,
        d.is_active,
        d.created_by,
        d.created_date,
        c.dd_query_id,
        c.datasource_id,
        c.query,
        c.virtual_query_name,
        v.dd_dataview_id,
        v.dataview_id,
        b.dd_dashboard_id,
        b.dashboard_id,
        r.dd_report_id,
        r.report_id,
        r.report_type_name,
        r.virtual_report_name,
        t.dd_table_view_id,
        t.data_source_id,
        t.table_view_id,
        t.virtual_table_name,
        w.dd_webservice_id,
        w.password,
        w.username,
        w.virtual_webservice_name,
        w.webservice_url
    FROM
        tbi_dd_config_master d
            JOIN
        tbi_dd_custom_query_config c ON d.dd_metric_config_id = c.dd_metric_config_id
            JOIN
        tbi_dd_dataview_config v ON d.dd_metric_config_id = v.dd_metric_config_id
            JOIN
        tbi_dd_dashboard_config b ON d.dd_metric_config_id = b.dashboard_id
            JOIN
        tbi_dd_report_config r ON d.dd_metric_config_id = r.dd_metric_config_id
            JOIN
        tbi_dd_table_view_config t ON d.dd_metric_config_id = t.dd_metric_config_id
            JOIN
        tbi_dd_webservice_config w ON d.dd_metric_config_id = w.dd_metric_config_id
```

I have searched for some links and tried different approach to create view, but unfortunately i end up with same result

```
CREATE VIEW tbi_dd_detail_view AS
    SELECT 
        d.dd_metric_config_id,
        d.metric_name,
        d.keywords,
        d.domain_id,
        d.is_active,
        d.created_by,
        d.created_date,
        c.dd_query_id,
        c.datasource_id,
        c.query,
        c.virtual_query_name,
        v.dd_dataview_id,
        v.dataview_id,
        b.dd_dashboard_id,
        b.dashboard_id,
        r.dd_report_id,
        r.report_id,
        r.report_type_name,
        r.virtual_report_name,
        t.dd_table_view_id,
        t.data_source_id,
        t.table_view_id,
        t.virtual_table_name,
        w.dd_webservice_id,
        w.password,
        w.username,
        w.virtual_webservice_name,
        w.webservice_url
    FROM
        tbi_dd_config_master d,
        tbi_dd_custom_query_config c,
        tbi_dd_dataview_config v,
        tbi_dd_dashboard_config b,
        tbi_dd_report_config r,
        tbi_dd_table_view_config t,
        tbi_dd_webservice_config w
    WHERE
        d.dd_metric_config_id = c.dd_metric_config_id
            AND d.dd_metric_config_id = v.dd_metric_config_id
            AND d.dd_metric_config_id = b.dashboard_id
            AND d.dd_metric_config_id = r.dd_metric_config_id
            AND d.dd_metric_config_id = t.dd_metric_config_id
            AND d.dd_metric_config_id = w.dd_metric_config_id
```

Can someone please figure out and help me where I am doing wrong?

Join with 3 tables and output :
[image]

Comment: Can you show sample data?

Comment: what are your table like? Can't you build it up one table at a time?

Comment: Yes we can do in single table also, as data is more we opted to separate tables and joining it while retrieving data

Comment: @Jens i have sample data image from 2 tables. check it

Comment: I believe `JOIN` is shorthand for `INNER JOIN` which will necessarily restrict the data being displayed. Consider using `FULL OUTER JOIN` and seeing what happens.

Comment: Likely what @Dai says, except you are most probably looking for LEFT OUTER JOIN if dd_metric_config_id joins to one and only one of the other tables.

Comment: Without having the table definition, it is difficult to suggest the options. 
What @e4c5 suggested that.. you should join one table at a time to create the view and test at which point the view is failing to display the expected result.
One more thing that Dai suggested that you are using INNER JOIN (JOIN).. you can also use LEFT JOIN and see what happens..

Additionally.. you can also test your JOIN query to test if it returns any data and then try to create the view and query the view to see the results.

Comment: LEFT JOIN and LEFT OUTER JOIN worked same for me. it is showing data also. but not exactly the data I am looking for !

Comment: @e4c5 as per your suggestion, is it good to create single table with exactly same fields i have mentioned in my question?? It wont effect the performance?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, I meant try a two table join, when you get it working build it upto 3, then add the fourth and so on.

Comment: What type of data are you looking for ?

Comment: @Maverick i have added output of joining 3 tables using LEFT JOIN. It is giving output as i edited my question. dd_metric_config_id = 5 should give 2 datas only, instead it is giving 4datas and dd_query_id is repeating

Comment: @Maverick same output even with DISTINCT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having the table definition, it is difficult to suggest the options.

At first you should join two tables to create the view and add another table at a time in the join condition and test at which point the view is failing to display the expected result.

You can also use `LEFT JOIN` and add `group by` clause at the end of the query and see what happens..

Example:

Use `LEFT JOIN` and append `group by d.dd_metric_config_id` at the end of the query.